# Rails: Net::OpenTimeout execution expired with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, httparty

My app is supposed to get JSON data from an external URL. It was working just fine until this morning. I see this error message:

Net::OpenTimeout in CommandesController#generate
execution expired

I have changed NOTHING and I can still access the external json url from a browser. Can you please help me ?

Here is the code that creates the issue:

```
    @data = HTTParty.get(URL).parsed_response
```

Answer (score 1):

The external site may be causing the timeouts. Try increasing the timeout period.

```
@data = HTTParty.get(URL, timeout: 60).parsed_response
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. Still get "Completed 500 Internal Server Error"

When I go on the external website via my browser it works directly without waiting.

Comment: Is it a public site? What is the url?

Comment: No it can not be disclosed here. I deployed my app on Heroku and it works fine. Don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with this error raising occasionally. What helped was to:

```
require 'resolv-replace'
```

Looks like it's was an issue with how Ruby resolves DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve the issue by adding verify:true to HTTParty so that it forces SSL acceptation

```
@data = HTTParty.get(URL, verify:true).parsed_response
```